# Embedding Winmd to a dll and using the dll in an C# app

Tags: dll, windows-runtime, uwp, dynamic-linking, winmd

How can I link a Winmd component (UWP 10) to a dll so that when I use the dll from an app.exe it can execute WinRT functions without showing TypeLoad Exception.

I could link the winmd component to a portable class library (Windows UWP) and the dll is getting generated fine. The problem is when I usee the dll in an app it throws exception (typeLoad) .

Or is there anyway to merge the Winmd component & dll to a single dll?

I dont want to specify the Winmd component through references in the app.exe

Regards, 
Sharmistha